# Should I add .idea/workspace.xml to gitignore?

Tags: git, webstorm, gitignore

When I try to checkout another branch, I get this error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        .idea/workspace.xml
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

I did some research and it seems some people avoided this problem by adding the afformentioned file to `gitignore`.

Is this a wise thing to do? If `git` is ignoring your `workspace.xml` file, won't it mess up your experience in the IDE (in my case, Jetbrains Webstorm)?

Comment: I have all the folders in gitignore `.idea/`, also the NetBeans metafiles and all metafiles in general. The *experience in the IDE* is globally saved afaik, not on a per project basis. If you are unsure, you can move the workspace.xml to your desktop, and test how it effects your experience.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Based on [JetBrains](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393067-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems?flash_digest=57e52233e688868381ba9266eef953823b82a4be) you should not place the *workspace.xml* and *tasks.xml* in repo, as they contain user specific settings.

Comment: But will that make my workspace change strangely if I hop between commits or branches?

Comment: I never had an issue, then again, in most cases, I add .idea folder in the gitignore as not everyone in the team uses intellij. I just gave you the link to the official/recommended practice.

Comment: @Imray - It could cause issues if the files change a lot between branches\commits, but webstorm should be able to handle this (please file an issue w/ jetbrains if you find that it doesn't). OTOH, this saves you from having to do a merge on workspace.xml every time you fetch someone else's changes (which could cause more issues if merged incorrectly).

Comment: So, if it's a private repo that only **I** am going to use it, is it no problem if I add it?