# What exactly is .idea/workspace.xml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had not heard of this file until I randomly checked `git status` in an old repository and there it was, a file I had not edited myself nor ever seen before. I do not know how it got there.

It seems it's common asked about - mostly how to remove it (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973506/cannot-ignore-idea-workspace-xml-keeps-popping-up) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647889/should-i-add-idea-workspace-xml-to-gitignore)).

What is this file, and what created it?

Comment: `.idea` is generally created when you are using Rubymine IDE.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I have never heard of Rubymin. I guess it’s possible I used it briefly for something as the repo has been untouched for some months

Comment: You can also check if it's not somebody else that forgotten to gitignore his IDE config file and  added it to the repo

Comment: I strongly suggest ignoring .idea/workspace.xml, if it is already in the repo and keeps popping up, follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973506/cannot-ignore-idea-workspace-xml-keeps-popping-up

The reason for ignoring this particular file is that it changes all the time for all possible reasons, including elapsed time.You don't want to see it every time you do any kind of a merge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

.idea is the dir for saving the project configurations for all Jetbrains IDES (RubyMine , Pycharm , PHPStorm , WebStorm ..etc)

you can handle it using two ways if you don't want to commit it to the repo

Ignore it only for yourself

in `.git/info/exclude`

add `/.idea`

Ignore it  in .gitignore  so it will be ignored for everyone who uses the repo

by adding `/.idea` to `.gitignore`

if the dir .idea already tracked by git you will need to remove it first from the cached files before ignoring by `git rm -r --cached .idea`

This folder can include important configuration if you did any custom configuration for the project and also include the indexed data for the IDE which helps it to provide quick autocomplete and in certain cases would be better to commit it to the repo but I always ignore it because the other developers in the team don't use RubyMinee